# How to run a loop in matlab even a struct condition satisfies and warning message?

Tags: matlab, loops, struct, warnings

Lets say I have a struct with three 1x1 struct elements with 5 fields in them respectively, the struct is GroupA and 1x1 struct elements  are A,B,C and each has 5 fields in them say ID, E, F, G and h. I Need to check for each of them if h is same in any both and give a warning saying h is same in A & B. For example:
struct GroupA

```
A         B         C
Id        ID        ID
E         E         E
F         F         F
G         G         G
h         h         h
```

I wrote

```
for B_card=1:size(GroupA,2)-1
  for C_card=(B_card+1):size(GroupA,2)
    if strcmp(GroupA(B_card).h,GroupA(C_card).h)==1
      warning('The h is same in',GroupA(B_card).ID,'&',GroupA(C_card).ID);
    end
  end
end
```

I got two problems: one the loop end (not sure whether is ending or not, can't understand) when an if condition satisfies and the warning message is only showing " The h is same in". I am quite new to Matlab so explained as good as I can, please let me know if you need some more explanation and thanks for your help.

Comment: thank you i will go through them

Answer (score 0):

```
 for B_card=1:size(GroupA,2)-1
      for C_card=(B_card+1):size(GroupA,2)
        if strcmp(GroupA(B_card).h,GroupA(C_card).h)==1
          warning('The h is same in',num2str(GroupA(B_card).ID),'&',num2str(GroupA(C_card).ID));
        end
      end
    end
```

its working like this also & thanks every one